# Increased pressure of Liquid Pitch and Limestone (Bitumen/Asphalt) @ approximately 300 degrees Fahrenheit

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

If liquid pitch and limestone (20/80 mostly limestone) is pumped (appx. 5 gpm) out of a nozzle that restricts the flow compared to the flow that would be achieved straight out of the pump ( no restriction ), would there be a considerable/noticeable temperature increase due to the restriction and/or friction/turbulence from the fittings/path to the nozzle from pump? If not, then what reasons could there be for a temperature increase?

I know you can't use pv=mrt, but what formula/table is there that comes close to modelling this situation?